# dx-react-grid filter option 'equal' not working

Tags: reactjs, devexpress, devextreme

I have created a table with dx React Grid and in one of the columns, the data is being shown as colored empty blocks with the help of `DataProvider`,with each color corresponding to a number out of 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

Here is my Grid implementation snippet:

```
<Grid rows={rows} columns={columns}>
    <FilteringState />
    <SearchState />
    <RatingHeatmapProvider for={skillColumns}  />
    <IntegratedFiltering />
    //....
    <Table />
    <TableHeaderRow />
    <Toolbar />
    <SearchPanel />
    <TableFilterRow showFilterSelector iconComponent={FilterIcon} />
    //....
</Grid>
```

Other than filter options `['equal', 'notEqual']`, every other option such as `greaterThan`, `contains` etc works. 
All options in other columns that have text value displayed works.

In image below, the first 4 columns correspond to the one with colored blocks on display, the last column is another one with text values directly on display. As you can see, `filter = 3` should have shown me the green tile, it has not. Even `greaterThanOrEqual` or `lessThanOrEqual` works (not shown in image)

[image]

How do I fix this?

**[EDIT]: Note: As I just checked, even without DataProvider and banded columns, i.e. showing the numbers directly this issue is present.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you store 'Rating' as 'number' in your database, don't you? When Grid processes the 'equal'/'notEqual' filtering operations, it compares value from a filter editor(`string`) and value from a row(`number`). It causes the described problem. This issue has been already [fixed](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/pull/1834). The fix will be available in the next update.

Currently, you can use a custom predicate as a workaround:

```
filteringColumnExtensions: [
  {
    columnName: "comumn_name",
    predicate: (value, filter) => {
      if (filter.operation === "equal") {
        return String(value) === filter.value;
      }
      // process other filter operations here...
    }
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kw12oyl2no).

Comment: Just for this use case, then, making the numeric row value as `String(value)` also works. Thanks for the input. Appreciate it.